# Error When Trying to create trigger in table ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I got error when I want to make trigger in Toad to my table.

The code like this :

```
create table SEIAPPS_MODEL(MODEL_NO NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, MODEL_NAME VARCHAR(100))

create sequence SEIAPPS_MODEL_SEQ
start with 1
increment by 1

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_SEIAPPS_MODEL
BEFORE INSERT
ON SEIAPPS_MODEL
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT SEIAPPS_MODEL_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.MODEL_NO FROM dual;
END;
```

The error i am getting is :
    `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
          ;`

What am I missing ?

Comment: perhaps a `;` after a crete table    and   after cerate sequence  statments. And a `/` after the create trigger statment

Comment: could you please give me an example ?

Comment: I was able to execute these statements one by one successfully using SQL developer

Answer (score 1):

```
    create table SEIAPPS_MODEL(MODEL_NO NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, MODEL_NAME VARCHAR(100)) ;
--                                                                                 ^^^^
    create sequence SEIAPPS_MODEL_SEQ
    start with 1
    increment by 1
    ;
-- ^^^^

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_SEIAPPS_MODEL
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON SEIAPPS_MODEL
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    SELECT SEIAPPS_MODEL_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW.MODEL_NO FROM dual;
    END;
    /
-- ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query has no syntax errors. I am not sure why you are getting the error.

I executed the statements one by one and i am able to execute all three successfull....